# How to find archived object file?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver

I am doing the following to store an object as an archive:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.shapeLayers] forKey:@"mySavedArray"];
```

I know it works fine as I'm able to reload it. Question is, how can I find this file? I'd like to see its size after its archived to compare the archive to the .m file, and also eventually I might need to upload it to a server. Am I saving it correctly, or should I go about that a different way?

Comment: You can save it as a plist in the Documents folder and turn on iTunes file sharing.  I will add code later today.

Comment: @wolflink - I don't know if saving it as a pList will work, this is an array of ShapeLayers, I believe you can only save certain types to pList? Anyway, maybe I'm confusing it, will be interested to hear what you have to say. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard user defaults is stored in a single file in "*App Home Directory*/Library/Prefereneces/". The archived data is part of that file. It is not saved as a separate file. If you want to get the data size, use .length property of NSData.

```
NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.shapeLayers];
NSUInteger size = [archivedData length];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:@"mySavedArray"];
```

Comment: Thanks do you is there way to archive it into a separate file?

Comment: Use [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:]. Normally you would write files to the documents directory. If you want to save it somewhere else, specify a different file path.

NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *archiveFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.archive"];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dict toFile:archiveFile];